# What is a strictly positive definite covariation?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis, covariance, positive-definite

We have martingales $(M^1,...,M^d)$. What does it mean if the covariation $(\langle M^j,M^i\rangle)$ is strictly positive definite?

Does someone know a reference?

What does it mean if I integrate with respect to this positive covariation $\langle M^i,M^j\rangle$ ?

Comment: I would expect $\sum_{i,j}^{d}a_{i}a_{j}\langle M^{i},M^{j}\rangle>0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Comment: @Tobsn do you know a reference/literature?
What does it mean if I integrate with respect to this positive covariation $\langle M^i,M^j\rangle$ ?

Comment: @Tobsn: What you mean is to create a matrix $A$ with the entries $A_{ij}:=\langle M^i,M^j\rangle$ and then what's meant by $A$ beeing positive definite. But this not what's meant by *the covariation is positive definite*.

Comment: The post is not asking for an explanation of the covariance being positive definite but for what it means if $\langle M^{i},M^{j}\rangle$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the start, that the (quadratic)-covariation is positive definite has notting to do with the given martingales $(M^1,...,M^d)$.

The covariation is a symmetric bilinear form. And for symmetric bilinear form beeing *positive definite* is a well know definition. But for beeing definite you can't just consider the covariation on the set of semimartingales (the biggest set for which the covariation is defined, as far as I know), as all finite variation processes have zero quadratic variation and thus the zero-value is not unique. But if you consider the equivalence class $V$ in which all processes are identified, iff their difference has zero quadratic variation, then the zero-value is unique. This means for all $X\in V$ $\langle X,X\rangle\geq0$ and equality iff $X$ is the zero-value in $V$.

On this space $V$ the covariation is a positive definite symmetric bilinear from, which means it is a scalar product. Thus $V$ equiped with $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a inner product space.